# C# Alternative to Switch case with string

Tags: c#, string, performance, switch-statement

I have a method called `GetResult()` that directs to other methods depending on the `mode` string:

```
public double GetResult(string mode)
{
    switch(mode)
    {
        case "button1": return ReturnButton1();
        case "button2": return ReturnButton2();
        case "ch1div" : return ReturnCh1Div();
        case "ch2div" : return ReturnCh2Div():
        //And 26 more lines of these..
    }
 }
```

Note that the `mode` string is obtained from an excel table. So the calling is something like: `GetResult(GetDataFromExcel(ColumnName));`

My concern here is regarding efficiency. I am sure there is a better approach. Initially I thought about `enum`:

```
private enum mode : int
{
    button1 = 1,
    button2 = 2,
    ch1div = 3,
    ch2div = 4,
    //etc etc
}
```

But I am retrieving the `mode` as string from excel, I don't see how is it better by converting each `mode` from string to int first. I mean it is basically the same efficiency as the `switch(string)` right?

So what can I do regarding this situation to get a better performance?

Comment: i guess dictionary would do better job here. also why your method is void? and you are returning what?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary sorry it is supposed to be double. I am returning results as double, but I don't think the information is needed for my question.

Comment: I vote to reopen since this is not questioning how to refactor the code to make it easier to extend or maintain (in which case yes, a dictionary or polymorphic solution would help, but not necessarily in the efficiency department), but merely a performance-related one. It's similar but not quite identical to the cited answer.

Comment: well. it was actually needed. you can use `Dictionary<string, Func<double>>` for this purpose.

Comment: If duplicate is not enough search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+refactor+switch and see what are existing approaches. If none works for your case - ask new question (make sure to try different approaches and measure performance to see if it meets your goals and add this information to the new question)

Comment: @Ike - if this is performance related question please make sure to provide clear goals and what exactly this question is optimizing for (speed, code readability, code size, compiled size, memory usage...)

Comment: Ah yes -- totally agreed there and on providing measurements. Maybe it's best to keep it closed without a more rigorous question.